# lmer Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I would like to do a ANOVA to get to know, where there is significance. I already surched for an answer of my problem but doesn`t find the mistake.

names:

```
[1] "Tier_ID"       "species"       "Klima"         "Ressource"     "Datum"         "Gewicht"       "IngestionRate"
```

data frame:

```
'data.frame':   70 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Tier_ID      : Factor w/ 70 levels "Raupe1","Raupe10",..: 1 12 23 34 45 56 67 69 70 2 ...
 $ species      : Factor w/ 1 level "Agrotis exclamationis": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Klima        : Factor w/ 1 level "BL4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Ressource    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Kontrolle","N",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Datum        : Factor w/ 1 level "06.08.2015": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Gewicht      : num  7.8 4.1 10.8 51.2 33.3 17.9 40.6 11.7 35.1 7.1 ...
 $ IngestionRate: num  0.385 1.057 1.598 0.164 0.396 ...
```

I did subsets like this:

```
K_NPK<-subset(Agro,Agro$Ressource!="N")
```

my model:

```
mod4 <- lmer(IngestionRate~Ressource+(1|Gewicht), data=K_NPK)
```

it answers:

Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations

But if I do this subset

```
N_K<-subset(Agro,Agro$Ressource!="NPK")
```

and this model

```
mod4 <- lmer(IngestionRate~Ressource+(1|Gewicht), data=N_K)
```

If this runs there is no error.

I hope you understand what I try to do.
Can anybody tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Your model doesn't make sense. A random intercept should not be grouped by a continuous variable. Please explain what model you intend to specify.

Comment: Sorry, I´m not good in R because I do it the first time. I do not know what you want me to tell you. Can you please describe more detailed or do an example?

Comment: We need to know more about what you are trying to do (in a practical/scientific context).  We can see that "IngestionRate" is your response/dependent variable; what predictor/independent variables and what groups are you trying to test?  What is your experimental design?

Comment: Ah ok thanks. The "Ressource" (N,NPK and K) is the explanatory variable and as you can see the "Gewicht" is the random factor. I now want do a Post-Hoc Test to look, if the relationship between K and NPK is significant. But why does it work the way with N and K if it doesn´t make sense?

Comment: As @Roland says, it doesn't make sense to have a continuous variable as the grouping variable for a random-effects term; the term on the right-hand side of the bar, e.g. `g` in `(1|g)` must be a *categorical* variable.  If "Gewicht" is a continuous-valued nuisance variable (i.e., a numeric covariate you want to control for), then you just add it as a fixed-effect term.  This question might be better for r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org ...

Comment: `"Gewicht" is the random factor` What does that mean to you? Do you possibly want a random slope? What are your subjects? I'd think the `Tier_ID`. So, possibly you want `IngestionRate ~ Ressource * Gewicht +(Gewicht | Tier_ID)`, but I don't know. You should read an introduction to linear mixed effects models.